# Java - Pass on Variables to Method via Constructor

Tags: java, object, methods

Is it possible to send variables i need in a method via a constructor ?

I have 2 files:

```
public class Recording {

public int height;
public int diameter;
public int weight;

public Recording (int height, int diameter, int weight) {
    this.height = height;
    this.diameter = diameter;
    this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Leergut {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int height;
    int diameter;
    int weight;
    int code;
    int pfand;

    while (code != -1) {

        Recording r = new Recording(System.in.read(), System.in.read(), System.in.read());
        classify(r);
    } else {
        // to be continued
    }

}
public static int classify(Recording r) {

    if (height == 250 && diameter = 67 && weight == 365) { code = 0; return code;}

    else { code = -1; return code ;}
}
```

I am looking for a way to pass on height, diameter and weight ( as declared in Recording class) to the "classify" method.

Or do i need to declare the variables inside the method again, in order to make it work ?

PS: For the ones, who tried to help me in my first thread, I decided to make a new post, as it would grant a better overview.

Comment: Downvoted, because the question demonstrates no understanding of basic language features. You should read some java tutorials or java books for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

You could create getter and setter methods for the height, diameter and width variables in Recording. Then, call them within your classify method.

Example:

```
// Methods in Recording.java
public int getWidth() {
    return this.width;
}
public int getDiameter()
    return this.diameter;
}
public int getHeight() {
    return this.height;
}
```

And in the classify method, just get the values from Recording:

```
public static int classify(Recording r) {

    if(r.getHeight() == 250 && r.getDiameter() == 67 && r.getWidth() == 365) {
        // Do whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a suggestion**

You must initialize the variables, then create 3 methods that return the respective values

```
public class Recording {

     private int height = 0;
     private int diameter = 0;
     private int weight = 0;

     public Recording (int height, int diameter, int weight) {

         this.height = height;
         this.diameter = diameter;
         this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getHeight()
    {
         return height;
    }

    public int getDiameter()
    {
         return diameter;
    }

    public int getWeight()
    {
         return weight;
    }
}
```

---

```
public static int classify(Recording r) {

    if (r.getHeight() == 250 && r.getDiameter() == 67 && r.getWeight() == 365) { code = 0; return code;}

    else { code = -1; return code ;}
}
```

Comment: no need to use getters and setters but highly recommended because they are considered as clean code in java

Comment: @tung That's why I said it was a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass variables to a method you can go as this:

```
public void myMethod(int variable1, boolean variable2) {
    //method body
}
```

You can call it like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     int a = 2;
     boolean f = false;
     myMethod(a,f);
     // If static do:
     // ClassThatHasTheStaticMethod.myMethod(a,f);
}
```

As a side note:

```
while (code != -1) {
    Recording r = new Recording(System.in.read(), System.in.read(), System.in.read());
    classify(r);
} else {
    // to be continued
}
```

You cannot put a else statement following a while code block as it will result in a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

you mean this?

```
    public static int classify(Recording r) {

    if (r.height == 250 && r.diameter = 67 && r.weight == 365) { 
        code = 0; return code;
    }
    else { 
        code = -1; return code ;
    }
```

Your Recording class and its fields are public, which means that you can access them just by calling their name, dot, and the field you desire to get.

Comment: Tried it, looks great too! Getting an IOException for "Recording r = new Recording(System.in.read(), System.in.read(), System.in.read());" though. There has to be a way how to read the int values into the object.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a new approach. Declared the variables inside the method again (cant figure out how to call the Setter function with "System.in.read()"

```
public static int classify(Recording r) {

    int height = System.in.read();
    int diameter = System.in.read();
    int weight = System.in.read();

    if (height == 250 && diameter == 67 && weight == 365) {int code = 0; return code;}

    else { int code = -1; return code ;}
}
```

However, now my Object "Recording r" tells me that the variables cannot be resolved anymore
AND
the System.in.read(); for the 3 variables inside the method throw some sort of IOException.